# Org Mode Not calculating formula for whole column

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am trying to use org-mode table formulas in Doom emacs on a Mac. I am trying to follow [this guide](https://orgmode.org/manual/Column-formulas.html#Column-formulas). I have tried pretty much everything offered in that guide but so far I can only get a single cell to update with a formula, never a whole column.

[image]

I tried "=" in the cell below, C-c = and pretty much everything else in the guide I linked.

Comment: Did you try recalculating the table after entering the column formula? You can do this with `C-c C-c` on the TBLFM line, or with `C-u C-c *` anywhere on the table.

Comment: THANK YOU! (filler filler filler)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helping.

[image]

But I do not know an elegant solution for a single cell.

Comment: For you last comment, see [Field and Range formulas](https://orgmode.org/manual/Field-and-range-formulas.html#Field-and-range-formulas)

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the table after entering the column formula. You can do this with `C-c C-c` on the TBLFM line, or with `C-u C-c *` anywhere on the table.